# AS3 - How to post to Facebook wall from Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, post

By trying to post a message to the Facebook wall of a user I'm only receiving the latest information about the user such as friends and likes.

I'm using Flash CS 6 and AS3:

```
    var dorequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://graph.facebook.com/[user-id]/feed?message=helloworld&access_token=[token])
    dorequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
loader.load(dorequest);
```

I'm new to the Graph API - what do I miss here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an AS3 Facebook API by Adobe:

https://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

You need to handle the login first, but here is how you post to wall:

```
var params:Object = {   
    message: text,
    link: 'your link here',
    caption: 'Text to display 1',
    name: 'Text to display 2',
    description: 'Description',
    picture: 'image url here'
};

Facebook.api( 'me/feed', onComplete, params, "POST" );

function onComplete( response:Object, fail:Object ):void 
{
    trace( JSON.encode(response)  );
}
```